# Linq to SQL DataContext.SubmitChanges incorrect syntax near the keyword Where

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I am working on an existing application and am trying to update a series of values within a database using Entity Framework and the DataContext.

Using context.SaveChanges() this is giving me an error of

> There was an error when 'SubmitChanges' was called. object:  exception: System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException (0x80131904): Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'WHERE'.
>      at System.Data.Linq.ChangeDirector.StandardChangeDirector.Update(TrackedObject item)
>      at System.Data.Linq.ChangeProcessor.SubmitChanges(ConflictMode failureMode)
>      at System.Data.Linq.DataContext.SubmitChanges(ConflictMode failureMode)

This has only become a problem since adding

```
        var managerItem = entityDataContext.item.Single(f => f.Id == consoleItem.ID);
        managerItem.ItemCount = itemCount;
        managerItem.Cost = Cost;
        managerItem.Submit = true;

        entityDataContext.SubmitChanges();
```

After this error there are also two other errors that occur, one being the same as mentioned above,

the other

> exception System.Data.Linq.ChangeConflictException: Row not found or changed.

However, the values I need to get updated are being updated so it I can only assume something else is or isnt happening.

Any and all help with the initial error would be gladly received.

Comment: Does your schema match your entity? Can you view the entire query that might help you with the bad clause (stacktrace, using sql profiler, etc)?

Comment: The using statement disposes of the context, which means that the change tracking gets reset after being disposed.

Comment: You could use SQL Profiler to check the query error in the `SqlException`.

Comment: I will try a stack trace this morning and let you know how I get on, and to be totally honest I completely forgot about SQL Profiler so will try that too.

Comment: Stack trace shows that its trying to update a table by using exec sp_executesql N'UPDATE [dbo].[table]
SET 
WHERE ([Id] = @p0) AND ([EntityTypeId] = @p1) AND ([DateUpdated] = @p2)

but is missing what is should be setting... I have added two new columsn in the database and manually updated the entity.dbml  to reflect these changes however... the table I updated is not the table that is having the trouble. 

Any suggestions?

Comment: Believe I have found my issue, where this is being called is in some of our middleware between two systems, the data was being changed, however it was checking if the new value and the system value are the same.  As the values were different the row did indeed not exists with this data.  so have changed this check. 

using the SQL profiler worked in order to help fix this issue thank you