# Linq to SQL DataContext missing SET clause on calling SubmitChanges

Tags: c#, linq-to-sql, datacontext, submitchanges

I am currently stumbling across some C# Linq to SQL DataContext misbehavior when retrieving a data set, changing it and invoking SubmitChanges to save the changes back to the database.

I searched around and found [this SO-Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30463638/linq-to-sql-datacontext-submitchanges-incorrect-syntax-near-the-keyword-where) pointing out pretty much my exact problem.

Short outline:

- I am using Linq to SQL with SQLite, therefore without the Designer offered by VisualStudio
- I am creating a connection to an In-Memory-Database
- I am using a class derived from DataContext taking the connection to the base class and a Table property mapping the real table
- I have used the Log Property to retrieve the actual command send to the database, which is as follows:

  ```
  UPDATE [Roles]
  SET 
  WHERE ([Id] = @p0) AND ([Name] = @p1)
  -- @p0: Input String (Size = 4000; Prec = 0; Scale = 0) [ea34d99e-8ad5-4fa7-83f3-5cf3ac282da6]
  -- @p1: Input String (Size = 4000; Prec = 0; Scale = 0) [Role 1]
  -- Context: SqlProvider(Sql2008) Model: AttributedMetaModel Build: 4.7.3056.0
  ```

As you can see, the SET clause is empty, which is what I cannot understand at this point.

Since I am pretty sure that more information are required to understand the issue, feel free to ask me anything about it, I would be more than happy to get you aboard.

Any chance to get the code up here as a zip file or similar?

Comment: Is there a particular reason you are using LINQ to SQL rather than Entity Framework?

Comment: I never spent a look into the EF up until now, so Linq came along as the Framework I used to know a little at least. What would be the benefit of the EF? 
I hope this is not the reason for the downvote ^^

Comment: LINQ to SQL hasn't been actively developed for many years. Unless you have a _very_ strong reason to use it, you should look to move to EF.

Comment: Okay, was not aware of this fact. 
I gave it a try, was not that complicated (unit tests for the win), 
and works like a charm. 
Thanks for pointing me into the right direction.

Answer (score 1):

Moving to Entity Framework has solved the problem.